# set min width on <td> in a reactstrap Table

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I have searched for a solution with no avail. I need to set a minimum width on my RESPONSIVE table columns in a Table imported from reactstrap.

This table is always going to have a DYNAMIC amount of columns. I have a select as my `<th>` and I want to set the  to a minimum width so users can obviously read the select options.

Here is my component below

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { CustomInput,Input, Table} from 'reactstrap';


const TableComponent = ({ register, errors, watch }) => {
  
  const TableRow = ({ data }) => (
    <tr className="align-middle">
      {data.map((customer, index) => (
        <td className="text-nowrap" key={index}>{customer}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
 
  return (
    <Fragment>   
    <Table responsive bordered striped hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            fileContacts.map((contact, index) => ( 
                <th className="bg-primary pr-1 pl-1 pt-2 pb-2" scope="col" key={index}>
                  <Input
                  type="select"
                  className="fs--1"
                  name="selectHeader"
                  id="selectHeader"
                 >
                   <option>First name</option>
                   <option>Last name</option>
                   <option>Email</option>
                 </Input>
                </th>  
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
        upload.contacts.slice(0, 10).map((customer, index) => (
          <TableRow data={customer} key={index}/>
        ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default TableComponent;
```

Here are two images. These are what it looks like on mobile or smallest laptop size

[image: before scrolling]

[image: after scrolling to the right a little]

Comment: Could you please also share with us an image of the visual output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. In the TableRow component that is being rendered in the body, you need to add a style prop to the `<td>`

Note: this must be an object within jsx brackets or else you will get an error.

Here is a copy of the TableRow

```
const TableRow = ({ data }) => (
    <tr className="align-middle">
      {data.map((customer, index) => (
        <td  style={{minWidth: 150}} key={index}>{customer}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
```

Here was my expected output

[image]